# Web API using Web.Config file of another Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two web api projects

- Yugasat.Authentication.ServiceLayer
- Yugasat.User.ServiceLayer

each with its own web.config files

[image]

[image]

For some reason the `Yugasat.Authentication.ServiceLayer` project is using the web.config file of the `Yugasat.User.ServiceLayer` project. When I add invalid text to the web.config file of the `Yugasat.User.ServiceLayer` project

[image]

and run the `Yugasat.Authentication.ServiceLayer` I can see that it is using the wrong web.config file

[image]

Is there any reason why this will happen?

Comment: edit your project files manualy

Comment: Have you checked the properties of the file. (Right click -> properties). You will see the full path to the web.config.

Comment: @KurtisHardy had a look at the properties and both projects are pointing to the correct location.

Comment: @Ewan what do I edit in the project file?

Comment: I eventually just deleted my config files on both projects and recreated them.

Comment: You could try excluding the web.config for Yugasat.User.ServiceLayer and reload the URL.

Comment: Also have a look at the csproj file (using Notepad or something) and look at the path to the web config. It should be something like
  `<ItemGroup>.... <Content Include="Web.config">....
  </ItemGroup>`